# Apache vhost deny directory access unless url rewritten

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have an apache vhost setup that I want to only have access to particular directories. So I have this in my vhost config:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/legacy_partners.inc
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all

</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/partner*>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My problem is that I have some rewrite rules that change the directory accessed e.g. "migrated". So what I want to do is allow access to the directory only if the URL has been rewritten from an allowed directory. So rewritten from /partner to /migrated

Is this possible?